# How to bypass step-up voltage converter?

Tags: step-down, step-up

I bought this [great solar panel unit on amazon](https://www.amazon.ca/Exodus-SP18-Rechargable-Electronic-Compatible/dp/B07H112BY4/ref=sr_1_6?dchild=1&keywords=12v%20solar%20panel&qid=1597019555&sr=8-6) that has lithium batteries, 12v input and 12v output. I use it to power a 5v ESP8266 and I have a step down voltage converter from 12v to 5v on my end but the batteries on the unit are not lasting as long as I was expecting (~2 weeks) and the sun doesn't seem to charge the batteries fully.

I opened the unit, it has a 8v (2x18650 lithium batteries) battery pack and a bunch of step-up and step-down converters and other features on the circuit to display an LEDs scale for the charge amount.

Would anyone have any suggestions on what components I should look for to bypass the step-up voltage converter? Because of that converter, on my esp8266, I cannot check the battery status (voltage seems to step up whatever is left on the battery to 12v) and I suspect it consumes quite a bit batteries.

At the bottom of the picture is the output, but I'm a bit puzzled as to why there is a CR43-4R7 which is usually a step-down converter.

[image: Circuit]

Comment: Questions on the *usage* of products, especially *undocumented* ones are not on topic here.  It would generally seem that you have purchased the wrong product for your intended usage.

Comment: I never really thought much about why they use 4R7 instead of 4U7 which might be more intuitive but 4R7 is more familiar with resistors

Comment: The part labeled '4R7' is neither a step-down nor a step-up converter. It's an inductor, which could be a part of one of either of those.

Comment: If the input is isolated from the output then you should be able to measure and bypass the output easily. Just use a multimeter and measure the various points on the board around the lower switching regulator circuit. Should be obvious which pins are the input and output of it.

Comment: @brhans thank you - that pointed me in the right direction. A little research on inductors and step-up converts showed me that these converters usually consist of an inductor, diode and capacitor. Sounds like if I can find the input of the inductor, that should have the raw battery output.